# Перенести элементы на уровень выше в инфоблоке в Битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте! Имеется инфоблок с 3-мя уровнями вложенности: продукция->категория товаров->бренды товаров. Нужно перенести **из** *брендов товаров* элементы **в** *категорию товаров*. Как это сделать с помощью API Битрикса? Прошу подсказать или хотя бы направить на путь истинный.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно:

1. Взять ID раздела из полей элемента инфоблока (IBLOCK_SECTION_ID)
2. Получить ID родительского раздела (SECTION) из полей этого раздела, получив их при помощи функции [CIBlockSection::GetByID](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/getbyid.php)
3. Привязать элемент к этому разделу при помощи функции [CIBlockElement::SetElementSection](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/setelementsection.php)